# Understanding 目のが

Tags: grammar

> 「わかってる。……でも、ああいう目**の**がよっぽどましよ。慣れてるから」

86─エイティシックス─Ep.3 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈下〉
安里アサト

I understand this sentence as "I know it. But since I’m used to it, those eyes might as well be good". The speaker and her friends are discriminated as "86".

But I don’t quite get why there is a の between 目 and が. Can’t we just say 目が?
What is the の doing here exactly?

[image: Picture]

Comment: タイプミスで「ほう」が抜けてるだけだと思います

Comment: I also think this is ほう. Here is the similar example from the manga I read other day: https://imgur.com/a/JXHMIem

Comment: タイプミスではないです。崩れた話し言葉では、「ほう」を略しちゃいます。

Comment: See also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59311/14531