# Understanding ことのが

Tags: grammar, nominalization

> 幸い、アネットはそう遠くまで行ってしまったわけではなかった。
>
> 交差した廊下の、角の壁に背を預け、小さな子供みたいにふてくされた顔をしている。
>
> 「……もういい。ほんとに、最後に喧嘩した時のことなんて全然覚えてないみたいだから」
>
> レーナが近寄ると、こちらを見ないまま拗ねた口調で吐き捨てた。
>
> 「あたしはシンを助けてあげられなくてそれがずっと辛くて、でも、それは少なくとも今のシンにとっては大したことじゃなかった。あんなどうでもいい**ことのが**、まだどうにか記憶の端っこに残ってることだった。だったら今更、……思い出してもらわなくてももういいわ」

86─エイティシックス─Ep.4　─アンダー・プレッシャー─
安里アサト

Could you please explain why ことのが is used there? How should I understand this phenomenon? I don’t feel の is needed. Isn’t ことが sufficient there?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95269/5010), but I'm not totally sure even with this much of context... I'd say this is not a good sentence.

Answer (score 2):

That の puts あんなどうでもいいこと in comparison with something else, most probably 最後に喧嘩した時のこと or あたしがシンを助けてあげられなかったこと. You could read it as:

> あんなどうでもいいことの（方）が、まだどうにか記憶の端っこに残ってることだった。

But I find the way the sentence ends a little weird. I would think the following is more natural.

> あんなどうでもいいことの（方）が、まだどうにか記憶の端っこに残っていた。